# Resize background color/image base on new UIView's size?

Tags: ios, uiview, resize

How to make the view's background color change base on the size of view? I can re-size the view but seem the background color not change, it's fixed.

```
color = [view backgroundColor];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];                               
[view setFrame:rect];
[view setBackgroundColor:color];
```

Comment: you want to change background color when you change size of your View ??

Answer (score 2):

You have set the background color of view to `ClearColor` , So it's not being changed.

Try,

```
color = [view backgroundColor];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];                               
[view setFrame:rect];

// here you need to set the 
color = [UIColor redColor]; // or the color you want to change

[view setBackgroundColor:color];
```

Comment: @Quang Luu .. If this is the answer of your question , then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the setFrame Method of the View then only Your Change background color will be called when ever you change the size of View....

Make subclass of a **UIView** and implement setFrame Method.

```
-(void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    self = [super setFrame:frame];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    //Put any condition here for specific background color using frame property of view
}
```